# Image rendering issue in UIActivityViewController and SLComposeController in iOS 7.0

Tags: ios, facebook, ios7, sharing, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am implementing sharing functionality in my application and i am facing problem at the time of facebook sharing. I have used below code to implement this with SLComposecontroller

```
   [mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:@"iOS 6 Social Framework test!"];
   [mySLComposerSheet addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.jpg"]];
   [mySLComposerSheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"test url"]];
```

Now i want facebook post like open graph style and for that i am using below code

```
[mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:@"iOS 6 Social Framework test!"];
[mySLComposerSheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"test url"]];
```

Now i am getting same post on facebook like open graph style but i am facing image rendering issue at the time of posting status like below image.

[image]

is there any html page issue there or what i need to check for this? Let me know if you have any alternative for this.

Comment: check your image extension jpeg or jpg

Comment: thanks for your quick reply but it doesn't matter with image extension i have tried with png as well

Comment: if i am adding "test url" as "google.com" ,it will display image in that.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the screenshot you are posting, since it show that you are posting an URL not an image.

If you want the image to preview there you should add the image.

Comment: if i am adding [mySLComposerSheet addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"]]; then it will not post like open graph style its just update status with image.

Comment: What you want is not possible with the iOS native share dialog. If you add the URL to image the share dialog will show the safari icon.

Comment: do you have any idea about that how to remove this safari icon? i want to post only url in facebook status.